Using Gitlab as a Configuration Management Tool for My Jira Scripts (ScriptRunner)
Im currently trying to understand, in a very secure environment ( Jira instance under dmz network), how can I make a full linked repo with all my  Jira script with Gitlab ! It is possible that I make CI/CD with bash script and API rest to retrieve all my script and push them on GitLab ?
Thanks for everybody's help
I can't even request my API (dmz) for now
